# Exception loading pocketsphinx_jni while running PocketSphinxDemo on Android device

Tags: android, cmusphinx

I've been trying to get the Pocketsphinx demo for Android running on a device for a couple days now. Whenever I try to run the demo, however, I get this error in LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
```

then a bunch of more errors, but the important last one is

```
    at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PocketSphinxDemo.<clinit>(PocketSphinxDemo.java.18)
```

Line 18 in PocketSphinxDemo.java is

```
System.loadLibrary("pocketsphinx_jni");
```

When I go to the pocketsphinx_jni folder, located in /PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug, it appears to be empty. I am running ubuntu, if that is at all relevant. Is there anything that should be in this folder? What is causing this error? Any sort of answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I go to the pocketsphinx_jni folder, located in
>   /PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug, it appears to
>   be empty.

`System.loadLibrary` doesn't load a folder, it loads a library. `libpocketsphinx_jni.so` is a library built with `ndk-build` during the build process. `objs-debug/pocketsphinx_jni` is a temporary folder used to build this library, its supposed to contain temporary files. The library itself must be located in `Demo/libs/armeabi/
libpocketsphinx_jni.so`

> Is there anything that should be in this folder?

In this particular folder you should have files like `pocketsphinx_wrap.o.d`. Those files are created with `ndk-build`.

> What is causing this error?

You didn't run `ndk-build` or there were errors during `ndk-build` and you ignored them.

Comment: Thanks! When I re-ran ndk-build, I got an error. Somehow the linux-x86 folder in /android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuild got deleted and that was causing an error.